# Prove that $cosh(x)=\frac{1+tanh^2(\frac{x}{2})}{1-tanh^2(\frac{x}{2})}$

Tags: trigonometry

This is an exercise we made in class, but I can't wrap my head around the $2-\frac{1} {cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})}$ in step 2

$$cosh(x)=\frac{1+tanh^2(\frac{x}{2})}{1-tanh^2(\frac{x}{2})}$$

with

$$t=\frac{x}{2}$$
<=>

$$2cosh^2(t)-1=\frac{2-\frac{1}{cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})}}{\frac{1}{cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})}}$$

and because

$$cosh(2x)=\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2}=2cosh^{2}(\frac{x}{2})-1$$

we conclude

$$cosh(x)=\frac{1+tanh^2(\frac{x}{2})}{1-tanh^2(\frac{x}{2})}$$

Comment: what does $ch(x)$ means?

Comment: It stands for cosh(x) in my book, but I'll edit that now

Comment: I'm actually wondering why it isn't $1-\frac{1}{cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})}$ instead of the 2-...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit : $$\tanh(\frac{x}{2})=\frac{\sinh(x)}{1+\cosh(x)}$$
I suppose that you can continue...

By the way, in your step 2 :
$$2\cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})-1=\frac{\frac{1}{\cosh^2}}{\frac{1}{\cosh^2}}(2\cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})-1)=$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})}(2\cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})-1)}{\frac{1}{cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})}}=\frac{2-\frac{1}{cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})}}{\frac{1}{cosh^2(\frac{x}{2})}}$$

Comment: Thanks, I just figured something I didn't realise immediately; $1-tanh^2(x)=\frac{1}{cosh^2(x)}$ and therefor: $2-\frac{1}{cosh^2(x)}=1+tanh^2(x)$